# Auto Click a button on a web page

Tags: php, javascript

I need to auto click a button on a web page.
Basically i have a user interface to see the logs of the network printer. This page already has a option 'Save in CSV Format'.When i click this, i get a popup box which asks if you want to run or save that file.

The issue is:
I am creating another web page where i want that if a user clicks on 'Clickme' button, he automatically gets that popup box, which appears when i click on the 'Save in CSV Format' in that User Interface. Using HTTPFOX, i found out that 'Save in CSV Format' has this detail:

```
<td bgcolor="#333333" height="27" align="right"><input type="button" value="Save in CSV Format... " onClick="get_loglist()"></td>
```

Is there any way i can do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work. But why don't you figure out (using firebug for example) what the url of that CSV file is and load that url in an iframe?

Comment: Ya that sounds good. do you know how can i capture that URL?

Comment: If you already have firebug installed, have a look at the "Net" tab. See Firebug's webpage for more info http://getfirebug.com/network/

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want the same script to execute by pressing your custom button.

At first sight you would think it could work to make your own button as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="ClickMe" OnClick="get_loglist()"/>
```

But in the case that eventlisteners where added, you don't have the same functionality on a click (if there was an addEventListener which triggered another execution).
However it seems safer to me to do a SaveButton.click() or even create an event object and firing it at the SaveButton.

For getting the element with JS you could use [JQuery JS selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
var saveButton = jQuery('[attribute="value"]')
```

i.e.

```
var saveButton = jQuery('[value="Save in CSV Format... "]')
```

and something like (or addEventListener)

```
myCustomButton.onclick = function() { saveButton.click(); }
```

Or maybe even better the create & launch event as stated before. How is that?

Answer (score 0):

That popup is from browser. All you have to do is redirect to the CSV file and rest will taken care. In PHP you have to do something like,

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://yourwebsite.com/path/to/csv')
?>
```